# Pods can't resolve external DNS

Tags: linux, kubernetes, weave

I have a problem with `k8s` hosted on my own bare-metal infrastructure.

The k8s was installed via `kubeadm init` without special configuration, and then I apply `CNI` [plugin](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-installation)

Everything works perfectly expects external DNS resolution from `Pod` to the external world (internet).

For example:

I have `Pod` with the name `foo`, if I invoke command `curl google.com` I receive error
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com`

but if I invoke the same command on the same pod a second time I receive properly HTML

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

and if I repeat this command again I can receive errors with DNS resolution or HTML and so on.
this behavior is random sometimes I must hit 10times and get an error and on 11 hits I can receive Html

I also try to debug this error with [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) guide, but it does not help.

Additional information:
CoreDNS is up and running and have default config

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
```

and files `/etc/resolv.conf` looks fine

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local 
options ndots:5
```

the problem exists on `Centos 8`(master, `kubeadm init`)  and on `Debian 10`(node, `kubeadm join`)
`SELinux` in on `permissive` and `SWAP` is disabled

it is looks like after install k8s and weavenet problem appear even on the host machine.

I'm not certain where the problem came from either k8s or Linux.
It started after I have installed k8s.

what have I missed?

Comment: Unlikely a k8s or linux issue. Have you check in weave CNI pods log and coreDNS logs if there's any error?

Comment: I have checked a coreDNS logs and I do not see any problems 

```
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = xxxxxxxxx
CoreDNS-1.8.4
linux/amd64, go1.16.4, 053c4d5
```

even after enable debug it looks like it cant resolve DNS 
but I do not get CNI logs
should I debug `weave` or `weave-npc`?

Comment: Logs from `weave` pod 
INFO:  Error checking version: Get "https://checkpoint-api.weave.works/v1/check/weave-net?arch=amd64&flag_docker-version=none&flag_kernel-version=4.19.0-18-amd64&flag_network=sleeve&os=linux&signature=ESL%2BuQMDeDCc%2B6ELXxbcVXixAYnwPhup4ST1iayWlaA%3D&version=2.8.1": dial tcp 216.58.215.115:443: i/o timeout
INFO:  ->[192.168.1.166:6783|0e:f3:c2:1e:eb:d1(server55.local)]: connection shutting down due to error: read tcp 192.168.1.193:59301->192.168.1.166:6783: i/o timeout
Full log you can find on https://pastebin.com/r2azgUcw

Comment: Is the IP address the same in `/etc/resolv.conf` inside a Pod and for `kube-dns` Service?

Comment: @mdobrucki yes it is 

`
```➜  ~ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

➜  ~ kubectl get svc/kube-dns -n kube-system`
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   15d
```
sorry for the plain text but in comment, there is no way to use formating `10.96.0.10`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using different CNI plugin and setting it up from scratch. Remember when using `kubeadm` , apply CNI plugin after you ran `kubeadm init`, then add worker nodes. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model) you can find supported CNI plugins. If the problem still exists, it's probably within your OS.

Comment: I have tried with different plugins `flannel` and `calico` and the behavior was the same. 
and as you say the procedure was initialize via `kubeadm init` then apply `CNI` plugin and then join nodes, now I checking the third paragraph of [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues) because on my host are 3 nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and maybe this have a impact

Comment: Let me know, what you've established

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/resolv.conf. The conf file can set the nameserver to 8.8.8.8.